# How can I access another form of rails in one controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

I have two controller: User and Address. user has many address.

In user/address page, I edit one address of user in a popup window (when user click 'edit' buttion) like:

```
<div id=new-add-win><a class=close></a>    
<%= form_for(@addresses) do |f| %>
```

error come up:

```
undefined method `model_name' for ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Address:Class
```

In user controller,

```
  def address
      set_user
      @addresses = Address.where(["user_id = ?", @user.id])
  end
```

Routing:

```
 resources :users do
    collection do
      get :address
    end
    resources :addresses
  end
```

Comment: A `user` has many `addresses`, which particular address do you intend to edit?  Do you not need an address id?

Answer (score 1):

`form_for` can only accept argument as object but not collection.

`@addresses` is a collection actually.

My suggestion is:

1. List several addresses in user page.
2. Each address links to its edit page.
3. Then in edit page you set this specific address.

Comment: Yes, address is a collection. But actually I need realize this edit function in a pop up window.

Comment: That doesn't matter. Once you set controller and plain html version working properly you can go there easily. The main problem in question is you need to set correct object for form_for.